# Ubuntu One progress bar not being shown

Tags: ubuntu-one

I did a fresh install of natty today, and found that the Ubuntu One launcher wasn't showing a progress bar for uploads/downloads. How can I get this back?

Answer (score 1):

I am also experiencing this issue. Apparently the update manager in corrupting local files as per the bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/769817